# overlapping buttons

Tags: android-layout

i want to create this buttons layout

[image]

i did

```
         <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:lay="10dp">
                <View android:id="@+id/strut"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/notificacion_desactivado" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/alarma_desactivada" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/icono_notificacion_suelto" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

And now i have something like this:
[image] But don't know how to make the central button to overlap the relative layout, i used margin and padding but still can't make the button to step over the layout.

Comment: Too much level nesting. A single RelativeLayout is enough.

Comment: Just set a central dummy View (0px wide and tall). Set one button to its left, and another one to its right. And finally another one in the center. DONE.

Comment: yes, that was the solution, thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do this using a `ConstraintLayout`. Place the two buttons than need to appear below the 3rd button inside a `LinearLayout` and constrain the 3rd button accordingly.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
    
    <Button
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/buttonLayout"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/buttonLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/buttonLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/buttonLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is how the output will look like

[image]

Change the `android:layout_marginBottom` value to move the 3rd button up or down.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @El0din I see that you have not done this for any of the questions you have asked till now; but usually one accepts an answer as the solution by hitting the check mark next to the answer. **This** marks the answer as the solution and helps future users too.

Answer (score 1):

```
This code works for me :)
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <View android:id="@+id/strut"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/text_gray" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/strut"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/red" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/app_logo_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: nice solution, but when i click the left or rigth button overslap the central. But that works for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Your welcome my pleasure, I suggest that you use textview instead of button so that you can customize your view :)

Comment: textview yes, that's the answer to my app, i will aply on the next version, really thanks!